# Часть кода в отдельный класс

Tags: android

Ребята, помогите разобраться. Я написал свою первую программу, теперь хочу функции вынести в отдельный класс. Я никогда этого еще не делал, подскажите что не так.

Вот кусок кода

```
if(reed==12){ // ecли пройдено 12 ячеек
    if(tobe){// если нажат пункт меню ToBe...
        if(mySettings1.contains(Tobe_ArrayList)){// если сохранен Tobe_ArrayList

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySettings1.edit();
            editor.remove("Tobe_ArrayList"); // удаляем Tobe_ArrayList
            editor.apply();


            displayResult2();

        }
        else {//ecли пройдено 12 ячеек и нажат пункт меню ToBe, но НЕ сохранен Tobe_ArrayList

            displayResult();

            listStr = new Gson().toJson(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrayl));// сохраняю Arrayl в строку

            Log.d("","Сохраненный Tobe_ArrayList:" + Arrayl);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySettings1.edit();
            editor.putString(Tobe_ArrayList, listStr);// cохраняем Arrayl в строке в SharedPreferences
            editor.apply();
        }


    }//End Push_ToBe

}//if(reed==12)

if(itenglish){// если нажат пункт меню IT English

    if(reed==12){// ecли пройдено 12 ячеек

        if(mySettings1.contains(ITenglish_ArrayList)){// если сохранен ITenglish_ArrayList

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySettings1.edit();
            editor.remove("ITenglish_ArrayList"); // удаляем ITenglish_ArrayList
            editor.apply();


        } // End ITenglish_ArrayList

        else{//ecли нажато меню IT English и пройдено 12 ячеек, но НЕ сохранен параметр ITenglish_ArrayList

            displayResult();

            listStr = new Gson().toJson(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrayl));// сохраняю Arrayl в строку
            System.out.println("Сохраненный ITenglish_ArrayList" + Arrayl);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySettings1.edit();
            editor.putString(ITenglish_ArrayList, listStr);// cохраняем Arrayl в строке в SharedPreferences
            editor.apply();
        }

    }// End reed

}// End itenglish
```

А вот, то что я пытаюсь сделать:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static android.view.View.INVISIBLE;
import static android.view.View.VISIBLE;
import static ua.languagetest.MainActivityTwo.ITenglish_ArrayList;
import static ua.languagetest.MainActivityTwo.Tobe_ArrayList;


public class SaveQuestions {

    SharedPreferences mySettings1;
    Activity activity1;
    int reed;
    //boolean tobe;
    boolean itenglish;
    String listStr;
    ArrayList<Integer> Arrayl;
    int right_option;
    int total;
    TextView myhint,question;
    Button resalt,back;


    public SaveQuestions(Activity activity0) {

        activity1= activity0;

    }

    public String menuTobe(boolean tobe) {


    if (reed == 12) { // ecли пройдено 12 ячеек
        if (tobe) {// если нажат пункт меню ToBe...
            if (mySettings1.contains(Tobe_ArrayList)) {// если сохранен Tobe_ArrayList

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySettings1.edit();
                editor.remove("Tobe_ArrayList"); // удаляем Tobe_ArrayList
                editor.apply();

                displayResult2();

            } else {//ecли пройдено 12 ячеек и нажат пункт меню ToBe, но НЕ сохранен Tobe_ArrayList

                listStr = new Gson().toJson(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrayl));// сохраняю Arrayl в строку
                Log.d("", "Сохраненный Tobe_ArrayList:" + Arrayl);

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySettings1.edit();
                editor.putString(Tobe_ArrayList, listStr);// cохраняем Arrayl в строке в SharedPreferences
                editor.apply();

                displayResult();
            }


        }//End Push_ToBe


    }//if(reed==12)

        return listStr ;




    }// End method menuTobe


    public String menuITenglish(boolean itenglish){

    listStr = null;

    if (itenglish) {// если нажат пункт меню IT English

        if (reed == 12) {// ecли пройдено 12 ячеек

            if (mySettings1.contains(ITenglish_ArrayList)) {// если сохранен ITenglish_ArrayList

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySettings1.edit();
                editor.remove("ITenglish_ArrayList"); // удаляем ITenglish_ArrayList
                editor.apply();

                displayResult2();

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(activity1, "Первая часть кода ToBe", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();


            } // End ITenglish_ArrayList



            else {//ecли нажато меню IT English и пройдено 12 ячеек, но НЕ сохранен параметр ITenglish_ArrayList

                listStr = new Gson().toJson(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrayl));// сохраняю Arrayl в строку
                System.out.println("Сохраненный ITenglish_ArrayList" + Arrayl);

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySettings1.edit();
                editor.putString(ITenglish_ArrayList, listStr);// cохраняем Arrayl в строке в SharedPreferences
                editor.apply();

                displayResult();

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(activity1, "Вторая часть кода ToBe", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }

        }// End reed

    }// End itenglish


        return listStr;


    }// End method menuITenglish

    void  displayResult() {//метод для вывода результатов 1 часть теста

        RadioGroup myRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) activity1.findViewById(R.id.radio_group);
        myRadioGroup.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);// скрываем радио-кнопки
        myhint.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);// скрываем подсказку
        question.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);// скрываем вопрос
        resalt.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);// скрываем кнопку ДАЛЕЕ
        back.setVisibility(VISIBLE);// делаем кнопку ГЛАВНОЕ МЕНЮ видимой

        TextView resultTV = (TextView) activity1.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        resultTV.setText("Тест завершён! Правильных ответов: " + right_option + " из " + total + "."
                +"Хотите еще больше вопросов? Ответьте на 12 из 12, возвращайтесь в главное меню и еще раз нажмите пункт меню. За каждый" +
                "тест вы получите бонус. ");
    }

    void displayResult2() {//метод для вывода результатов 2 часть теста

        RadioGroup myRadioGroup = (RadioGroup)activity1.findViewById(R.id.radio_group);
        myRadioGroup.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
        myhint.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
        question.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
        resalt.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
        back.setVisibility(VISIBLE);

        TextView resultTV = (TextView)activity1.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        resultTV.setText("Тест завершён! Правильных ответов: " + right_option + " из " + total + ".");

    }

}// End class SaveQuestions
```

В MainActivity:

SaveQuestions sq = new SaveQuestions(this);
                sq.menuTobe(tobe);

Comment: Прежде чем делить на классы, ознакомьтесь с принципами SOLID, а заодно и с паттернами проектирования. То что вы сделали сейчас несколько эээ...  нелепо.

Comment: Понял, спасибо, иду читать